# In how many ways can two different prizes be given to ten students?

Tags: permutations, combinations

In how many ways can 2 different prizes be given to 10 students if

(i) one student may receive both prizes?
(ii) no student can receive more than one prize?

Comment: Give us an example of a permutation/combination problem you *can* do, and we'll start from there.

Comment: Well...I can do stuff like "In how many ways can 3 letters be chosen from the set of vowels and what is the probability it is an "A" ?" 
The very basic stuff

Comment: So, what's the difference between choosing 3 letters from the set of vowels, and choosing 2 students from a set of 10 students?

Comment: I got that it's 10C1 to choose one student. I didn't know how to do the part where the distribution of the prizes is concerned. I started studying this section only last night so that's why I kinda suck at it...

Comment: But there are two prizes, not just one, so we're choosing 2 students. We'll worry about the distribution later. One thing at a time.

Comment: But, the first part states, "If one student is to receive both" In that case, isn't it 10C1?

Comment: The first part does *not* state that one student is to receive both; it states that one student *may* receive both. One step at a time!

Comment: Okay, in that case, its 10C2 = 45 right? Ooops, sorry about that

Comment: OK, that's the numer of ways to choose two students. But the two prizes are different. So, how many ways are there to give the two different prizes to the students?

Comment: Would that be 10C1* 2 = 20?

Comment: 10C1 (I'd rather write, $10\choose1$) is still choosing one student, but we're choosing two.

Comment: Okay, so we have 10C1 to select a student and again 10C1 to select the student who's gonna receive both prizes?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Okay so is it 10C1* 10C1 = 100? Because that's the correct answer stated with the question

Comment: Good! That's the answer when one student may receive both prizes. Now, what about the other part? How many of those 100 ways do you have to throw out? How many are left?

Comment: I think it should be 10C1 * 9C1 = 90

Comment: Looks good to me. Write it up!

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking time to help me!! @GerryMyerson. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Look at it from another angle.   Let's ask: How many ways can one student be selected for each of two prizes if:

(i) The prizes *may* share the same student — so the students are selected with repetitions allowed.

If a single student *may* receive both prizes then the prizes *may* be shared by the same student.   So the first prize may be given to any one of the 10 students, and then the second prize may also be given to any one of the 10 students.

(ii) The prizes *cannot* share a student — so the students are selected with repetitions disallowed.

If a single student *cannot* receive both prizes then the prizes *cannot* be shared by the same student.   So the first prize may be given to any one of the 10 students, but then the second prize may only be given to one of the other students.
Now can you count ways to perform the tasks?

Comment: I'm still confused as to how to select the student who is going to receive both prizes...

Comment: Why *must* a single student get both prizes? You should just be thinking about the number of ways that this can work out. Label the students A B C D E F G H I J. In case (i), the possibilities are AA AB AC AD AE AF AG AH AI AJ BA BB BC BD BE BF... can you figure out a way to count these?

Comment: You don't have to, @AbdullahZameek  If a single student *may* receive both prizes then the prizes *may* be shared by the same student.  So the first prize may be given to any one of the 10 students, and then the second prize may also be given to any one of the 10 students.

Comment: Okay I think I got it. 
For (i) its 10C1 * 10C1 = 100
For (ii) its 10C1 * 9C1 = 90

Comment: Thanks a lot guys! I got the correct answers